# Noda Time: Period.Between() returning incorrect number of days?

Tags: c#, nodatime

Given the code snippet below, why are the final four output periods the same? I would expect the Days portion for those lines to be 4, 3, 2, 1 not 4, 4, 4, 4. Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious? (It's late and I'm tired, so it's very possibly the latter.) I'm using Noda Time 1.2.0.

```
for (int day = 25; day <= 31; day++)
{
    var d1 = new LocalDate(2013, 12, day);
    var d2 = new LocalDate(2015, 3, 4);

    var period = Period.Between(d1, d2);
    Debug.WriteLine("Day: {0}, Period: {1}", day, period);
}

// I get the following output:
Day: 25, Period: P1Y2M7D
Day: 26, Period: P1Y2M6D
Day: 27, Period: P1Y2M5D
Day: 28, Period: P1Y2M4D
Day: 29, Period: P1Y2M4D
Day: 30, Period: P1Y2M4D
Day: 31, Period: P1Y2M4D
```

Comment: I guess the problem is located in `Period.Between` method

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, yes, I think so.

Comment: My first thought was maybe it had something to do with the month not having 31 days, maybe it considered 28 - 31 to be the same day. This might have been the issue for February, but considering you're using December, I doubt this is the problem.

Comment: Does your locality happen to have 28 days in the 12th month of the year?  Perhaps using a non-Gregorian calendar.

Comment: @Servy: Good question, but no. I'm using the default calendar system, which has 31 days in the 12th month.

Comment: Out of interest, now that you've read the docs do you consider this to be a flaw in Noda Time, or just an inherent piece of annoyance due to variable month lengths? I'm very open to suggestions of better ways of doing date/time arithmetic.

Comment: @JonSkeet: The latter. The more I thought about it, the more sense the results I posted in my question made. If there's a better way, I can't think of what it would be.

Comment: @Nick: Right. I'm not sure whether that makes me happy or sad...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of how the calculation of the period is done - from [Date and Time Arithmetic in Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/userguide/arithmetic.html): "the rule is extremely simple: **One component is added at a time, starting with the most significant, and wrapping / truncating at each step**."

So when it goes through that February, a truncation to 28 days happens. You can see the same thing happen with a truncation to 30 days if you edit your code to go from `(2013, 3, day)` to `(2013, 5, 4)`:

```
Day: 25, Period: P1M9D
Day: 26, Period: P1M8D
Day: 27, Period: P1M7D
Day: 28, Period: P1M6D
Day: 29, Period: P1M5D
Day: 30, Period: P1M4D
Day: 31, Period: P1M4D
```

If you get the period in terms of days only (`Period.Between(d1, d2, PeriodUnits.Days)`) then you get the expected descending count:

```
Day: 25, Period: P434D
Day: 26, Period: P433D
Day: 27, Period: P432D
Day: 28, Period: P431D
Day: 29, Period: P430D
Day: 30, Period: P429D
Day: 31, Period: P428D
```

Comment: Thanks. Guess I should have read the documentation more carefully.

Comment: Nice answer!  But please link to the new [nodatime.org](http://nodatime.org) site next time. I updated this one.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for the update. I got the information via google, and it didn't present nodatime.org to me. It does appear in the search results *today* though.

Comment: No problem. And happy new year!