# Calculate years, months, days between two dates

Tags: c#, date, nodatime

I am trying to display the years, months and days between two dates in a C# application that I am creating. (Using console for testing purposes)

I'm using NodaTime to achieve this but I am having issues rounding months up.

I have read most of the questions and answers here but didn't find anything that I could benefit from.

Most of the time the function works but sometimes it doesn't add the months if days > 30 (which would add a month)

I am using this code for testing

```
LocalDate start = new LocalDate(2017, 10, 16);
LocalDate end = new LocalDate(2018, 1, 15);
Period period = Period.Between(start, end);

Console.WriteLine("{0} years, {1} months, {2} days",
                              period.Years, period.Months, period.Days);
Console.ReadLine();
```

**(2017, 10, 16)** and **(2018, 1, 15)** should display as 3 [months](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=16&m1=10&y1=2017&d2=15&m2=1&y2=2018&ti=on) but they show as 2 months and 30 days ( I've tried to add **+1 to period.Days** but it's showing as 31 days after I do that). I need the end date included when I display the format.

Is there anything I can use to achieve what I need ?
I need to show the correct format: 2 years, 11 months, 3 days

Comment: it says in your link *Or 3 months **including the end date***. Maybe nodatime doesn't include the last day, but calculated the span *until* that date. If so, I guess you could just add one day to `end`?

Comment: Months aren't always ... days so the 16th to 15th is indeed a day less then a month. (`if days > 30 (which would add a month)` makes no sense, months aren't a constant 30 days)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102601/noda-time-period-between-returning-incorrect-value and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853499/noda-time-period-between-returning-incorrect-number-of-days

Comment: You need to fix a month as being 30 days and a year being 365 days to do what u want. After this, calculate total days between the two dates.

Comment: @FelipeDeveza Thought of that but I want to be display the correct format if possible, I need to include leap years and day variations in month (30-31)

Comment: As both the start & the end month have 31 days, then why isn't the correct result 2 months & 30 days. After adding 1 day try using the [Normalize](https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/api/NodaTime.Period.html#NodaTime_Period_Normalize) method. As days in the month are variable though once calculated a "Period" has no reference to a particular month - so converting 2 months 30 days to 3 months cannot reliably be done.

Comment: @PaulF I have tried to use DateTime.DaysInMonth Method but I can't find a  way to utilize that, any ideas ?

Comment: I would have thought that defining a period using months and days like that is going to give results that are difficult for the user to interpret, since the months are (potentially) different lengths. Just giving years and days would better, IMO (even though years are also different lengths!).

Comment: @Nex: When using a "Period" the concept of months & days becomes a very complex issue - as I said in my first comment, both October & January have 31days, so using either of those as a reference point, the correct answer is 2months 30days. The answers in LocEngineers links all say pretty much the same thing - but they are worth reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is indeed that you're using the "include end date in calculation" in timeanddate.com. The solution isn't to add a day to the *period* in Noda Time - it's to add a day to the *end date* before you perform the calculation:

```
Period period = Period.Between(start, end.PlusDays(1));
```

That will then give you your expected output:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        LocalDate start = new LocalDate(2017, 10, 16);
        LocalDate end = new LocalDate(2018, 1, 15);
        Period period = Period.Between(start, end.PlusDays(1));

        Console.WriteLine(
            $"{period.Years} years, {period.Months} months, {period.Days} days");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 years, 3 months, 0 days
```

When thinking about "between" questions like this, I like to try to think of really simple examples.

What's the period *between* January 23rd 2018 and January 24th 2018? Noda Time and I both say "1 day". (Add 1 day to January 23rd and you get January 24th.) If you're talking about the period of time *covered* by the date interval of January 23rd 2018 to January 24th 2018, then that's two days.